# How to persist string array using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

how to persist string array in a row using JPA ?

I have tried with couple of open source dependency even tat's not working , let if you have any approaches to get this done .

Comment: If the database supports arrays (like PostgreSQL), you can use [this library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor) without any special modifications to your code, other than the `columnDefinition` if you use Hibernate to maintain the table structure, rather than doing it manually (much safer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check @Converter from jpa. You need to create convert and unconvert methods for your custome converter. Something like this http://hantsy.blogspot.com/2013/12/jpa-21-attribute-converter.html?m=1